# Azuracast listener statistics shows decimals values, what does that mean?

Tags: internet-radio

I want to see the amount of listeners of my radio station over the time. But the graphic shows values like "0.67 listeners" instead something like "12 listeners". I don't get how to read the `y` axis. Some clues?

[image]
thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The listener count shown in the statistics is the average listener count across the entire day, as a sum total of each measurement point (15 seconds or less apart from each other) added together and averaged.

([From a GitHub issue](https://github.com/AzuraCast/AzuraCast/issues/1628#issuecomment-498906552))

Comment: mhh, so how much listeners are "0.67"?